# Cannot invoke [Method] with argument list of type ( , )

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have two protocols `A` and `B` where `B` inherits from `A`.

```
protocol A { }

protocol B: A { }
```

And I have a utility class which has function called `add` whose parameter should conform to the protocol `A`:

```
class Utility {
    func add<T:A>(t:T.Type,param:T){
        ....
    }
}
```

Then I have a test class which creates object of `Utility` and calls its function `add` which accepts a parameter of type `B` (class object which implements `B`):

```
class Test {
    var util: Utility

    init() {
        util = Utility()
    }

    func addItem(data:B){
        util.add(B.self,param: data) // This line produces Cannot invoke add with argument list 
    }                         // of type (B.Protocol,param:B)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please simply copy and paste your code to avoid posting mistakes.

Comment: I think your case can be simplified down to this: http://swiftstub.com/171514009.  It seems that Swift can not handle protocol type of arguments in generic functions with constraints.  Don't know (yet) if that's a bug or by-design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that you are trying to accept variable as a protocol, not the type conforming to the protocol:

```
func addItem(data:B){
    util.add(B.self,param: data)
}
```

Which is strange, because you did it right in the `Utility` class. Simple fix is to do exactly the same here (using constraints):

```
func addItem<T: B>(data: T) {
    util.add(T.self, param: data)
}
```